# Programming nRF24LE1 with the AVRISP

Tags: avr, programmer, 8051, isp

Is it possible to program the nRF24LE1 with an AVRISP mkII? It has an Intel 8051, and I've noticed that AVR also supports this instruction set, so perhaps they already have a compiler in AVR Studio? Otherwise how would I go about integrating sdcc in? Otherwise how could I program the nRF24LE1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two devices share the same instruction set, that is no guarantee of compatibility. They may be completely different in terms of program memory space, peripheral memory map, programming interface, etc. The ISA implementation might even be quirky, but that's another story. For now, you have two concerns: 1) compiling code and 2) programming the device.

First, you can't use AVR Studio to compile because it only support AVRs, as you can see from the [list](http://www.atmel.com/tools/ATMELAVRSTUDIO.aspx?Products=010%20Atmel%20AVR%208-%20and%2032-bit%20Microcontrollers&tab=devices). (I don't know if earlier versions have 8051 support.) From googling, it appears that you could use sdcc/makefiles, sdcc/Eclipse, or one of the many for-pay 8051 development environments.

Second, AVRISP does not support the Nordic part. AVRs and the Nordic part both look like SPI Flash for programming purposes, actually, but the Flash command set is completely different. In *theory* you could use the AVRISP hardware, but you would have to write your own software or modify avrdude appropriately; not a walk in the park. From some googling, users of this chip have written their own programmers, using various microcontroller platforms. So you appear to have the option of implementing your own programmer, or purchasing Nordic's.

Answer (score 0):

AVR Studio only supports the AVR, you need an 8051 assembler or compiler if you want to develop code for the nRF24LE1. Keil can supply suitable tools: http://www.keil.com/dd/chip/4727.htm

Comment: But some of their chips are 8051s... so I thought perhaps there's a way to utilize this?

Comment: The AVR architecture is distinct from the 8051.  The name of the COMPANY is Atmel (not AVR).  Atmel makes both 8051 and AVR microcontrollers.  Their most popular line is the AVR and it has in many ways become synonymous with the company, but that doesn't mean their 8051-based and AVR-based offerings are compatible.